# why does sencha app build production replace my css file?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, compass-sass, dev-to-production

I've had to go back to an old version of compass: 0.12.7 
Otherwise it fails on missing files. Before installing I removed the existing compass installation.

It correctly compiles my css file when I make a change to the scss file.

But when I ask sencha to make a production build with "sencha app build production" the css file in my project gets replaced with a different one.

The file probably gets overwritten at the following line during the build process: 
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
overwrite ../css/app.css

So it claims to use my installed version of compass.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same problem i have met.
[Sencha touch 2.4.0 SASS compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214353/sencha-touch-2-4-0-sass-compile-error?noredirect=1#comment41112296_26214353)

You should not write your custom css in `app.css`.
IMHO, there are two ways to add custom css.
1. [app.json](http://html5wood.com/sencha-touch-2-x-how-to-include-custom-css-and-js-file-in-application/)
2. `@import` your custom scss file in app.scss in `resource/sass/app.scss` and then use `sencha ant sass` to compile css file.

Comment: Thanks I was indeed importing a css file instead of an scss file. But importing the scss file causes more errors because it can't find the font parts. Btw I'm trying to use font-awesome here.

Comment: so you need to add this css file in `app.json` in first means

Comment: Yes I tried including the css file, in the css block of my app.json file. Does not help, does not matter which I do first.

Comment: apparently I also needed to include the font awesome resource files.